# Split data in one column to multiple columns based on duplicates with SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have current Data like this:
[image: this]
`image1`

I have the data as follows in the `image 1`

I want the data be modified like this
[image: this]
`image2`

I want the output as in the `image 2` using SQL query in oracle SQL developer.The duplicate of payment methods for one orderID should go into different columns .

Comment: Which DBMS are you really using. You shouldn't just tag all of them.

Comment: Oracle - sqldeveloper

Comment: SQL Developer is a client IDE. If you are using it to access an Oracle database then tag as [tag:oracle] and [tag:sql]. The version of Oracle (assuming it is actually that) also matters; pivot is available from 11g for example, Have you tried to use that? It's also better to use formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT RegistrationId,
       OrderId,
       TotalPrice,
       MAX( CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN online_attribute1 END ) AS online_attribute1,
       MAX( CASE rn WHEN 2 THEN online_attribute1 END ) AS online_attribute2,
       MAX( CASE rn WHEN 3 THEN online_attribute1 END ) AS online_attribute3
  SELECT RegistrationId,
         OrderId,
         TotalPrice,
         online_attribute1,
         ROW_NUMBER()
           OVER ( PARTITION BY RegistrationId, OrderId, TotalPrice
                  ORDER BY NULL ) AS rn
  FROM   Data
)
GROUP BY RegistrationId, OrderId, TotalPrice
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer

Answer (score 0):

> Hello. I am assuming that you are basically working on Oracle version.
>   I have tried to replicate the scenario in the below snippet. Hope this
>   helps.

```
SELECT a.id,
  a.ord_id,
  a.price,
  SUBSTR(wmsys.wm_concat(a.attr),1,instr(wmsys.wm_concat(a.attr),',',1)-1) att1,
  SUBSTR(wmsys.wm_concat(a.attr),instr(wmsys.wm_concat(a.attr),',',1)  +1,LENGTH(wmsys.wm_concat(a.attr))) att2
FROM
  (SELECT 'av@gamil.com' AS id,
    1                    AS ord_id,
    1000 price,
    'master_card' attr
  FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'av@gamil.com' AS id, 1 AS ord_id,1000 price,'Other' attr FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'sh@gamil.com' AS id, 2 AS ord_id,1060 price,'aramax' attr FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'sh@gamil.com' AS id, 2 AS ord_id,1060 price,'fedex' attr FROM dual
  )a
GROUP BY a.id,
  a.ord_id,
  a.price;

----------------------------------OUTPUT---------------------------------

ID           ORD_ID PRICE   ATT1          ATT2
av@gamil.com    1   1000    master_card   Other
sh@gamil.com    2   1060    aramax        fedex

----------------------------------output-------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer

Comment: If it helped. Can you plz accept the answer so it will be useful to others too.

Comment: `WM_CONCAT` is not a supported/documented oracle feature and is not available on all Oracle instances (it is [not available at all in Oracle 12c](https://blogs.oracle.com/oracle-database-app-admin/entry/why_not_use_wm_concat)). Also, this solution will fail (i.e. return incorrect values) if any of the attributes contains a comma.